# Why is the stress of lebendig on the second syllable?

Tags: pronunciation, stress

The [pronunciation](http://www.dict.cc/?s=lebendig) of *lebendig* lies on the second syllable, which does not follow the [stress rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_phonology#Stress.).

It has no suffix that would change stress from the root word (that is, *-ig*), nor such a prefix (the root *leben* has stress on the first syllable).

Can someone offer an explanation?

Comment: I am not sure there is an explanation. It's just the way it is. It used to be pronounced differently, i.e. l**é**bendig a long time ago, but pronunciation has changed over time.

Comment: By the way, the first vowel in *lebendig* is also an exception. The usual e-sounds in native German words are /eː/, /ɛː/, /ɛ/, and /ə/, but the first vowel in *lebendig* is a *short closed e* /e/, which otherwise occurs only in loan words.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Be aware that the following is only an educated guess.

Even ignoring the unconventional stress, *lebendig* is a peculiar word. It is the only German word formed this way¹, i.e., by appending *ig* to the present participle. Usually such adjectives are formed by appending an adjective ending to the basic stem (here, *leb*), as for example in *lebhaft, wendig, möglich.*

Relatedly, there are only few adjectives that²:

- have three syllables;
- end on a standard stem such as *ig* or *lich;*
- have no sort of morpheme boundary between the first two syllables, such as in *ge-bräuch-lich* or *in-halt-lich;*
- are not reduced in spoken language, such as *hügelig → hüglig.*

Many of those are based on loanwards, which are exempt from the stress rules anyway and are at times also stressed on the second syllable, e.g., *persönlich.* Moreover, only very few such words have a similar vowel sequence as *lebendig,* namely *ehelich, elterlich, flehentlich, leserlich, schwesterlich* and *wesentlich,* all of which are not unique in their formation. Finally, there are only three other such words ending on *ig,* namely *heimelig, morastig, minütig* (the latter two are based on loanwords and stressed on the second syllable). So, **the vast majority of three-syllable adjectives is stressed on the second syllable**.

Due to this lack of parallels, speakers could have started ignoring the origin of the word and stressing it in analogy to the many three-syllable adjectives starting with a prefix such as *behändig, gebrechlich* or *verlässlich.* This may be helped by the word starting with the typical prefix vowel *e.*

---

<sup>¹ All other German words ending with *endig* are derived from *wendig* and not from a present participle of a verb. Perhaps *wissentlich* has a comparable origin.

² Taking all three-syllable words from a dictionary ending on *lich* or *ig,* discarding those with common prefixes automatically and inspecting the rest by hand, I obtained a total of 66.</sup>

Answer (score 11):

Rule: In German, every rule has an exception.

In reality, rules are an oversimplified information, valid for a certain amount of time, to describe language. One tries to derive rules to organize properties of languages, but being a language as complicated as it is, one usually fails in encompassing all the cases.

I think you have to be glad there is a quite useful stress rule in German (that of the first syllable). People learning, say, Russian or English wish there would exist at least a little pattern.

Comment: _"Rule: In German, every rule has an exception."_ Does this rule have an exception?

Comment: Of course it does. The above quote is incomplete, it should read _For every rule there is an exception, including this one._ There is probably a corollary hidden somewhere, too, for what it's worth.

Comment: Yes. I think the exception to the rule above, @Chris, is the *-keit* nouns being feminine (all indeed are). I hope I'm wrong, though.

Comment: If there is an exception for the rule, that every rule has an exception, then there is a rule having no exceptions. So the original sentece is not true any more. Is it the same as Pinoccio saying "My nose will grow now"?